# sshpass for su / using su non-interactive way

Tags: bash, su, sshpass, non-interactive

I have Jenkins running on a functional account.

Sometimes I need to run 'echo blabla' on several boxes which are accessible from a proxy server only. In that case Jenkins runs:

```
~/bin/sshpass -p'$userJumpServerPassword' ssh ${username}@$jumpServer  ssh root@$targetBox echo blabla
```

That's great, because I provide userJumpServerPassword and username and then it login to root@targetBox using private keys stored on my individual account on a proxy server. userJumpServerPassword is masked so please ignore this aspect.

The other case I'm referring to is to reach servers which are not behind a proxy. I want to do something like that:

```
~/bin/supass -p'$localPassword' su $username -c ssh root@$targetBox echo blabla
```

to force Jenkins to switch to my individual account on localhost and then use private keys to connect to target box (no password).

And here's my problem. There is no such a thing like supass allowing to use su a non interactive way. Is there any walkaround? Using ssh to connect to localhost sounds funny.

Comment: Can you configure `sudo` on the target host[s] to not require a password for the command[s] you need to run?

Comment: No, unfortuantely I cannot.